# Notify of any new answers daily by e-mail

Tags: support, answers, notifications

At the bottom of my question is a text field for being notified "daily of any new answers."  I assume this is an e-mail address field, but there is no hint in the UI to indicate this.

I have not received any e-mails, either.  Is it because I'm a little too proactive about getting my question answered, and I've been checking the site every few hours?  Does that turn "new" answers into "already seen" answers, for the purposes of the daily e-mail?

**EDIT:**  Nobody has used the "notify" feature long enough (or at all) to know what it does?

Comment: Good question. I wasn't sure if it wanted a username or an email address and the fact it didn't give me any 'UI feedback' that it had accepted my entry I wasn't sure if was working either which is how I ended up here (Thanks google)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the notify feature twice. You use an email, which I admit I feel is rather obvious. I was emailed the day after posts were made in both cases, even though I already saw the answers by looking at the site.

Perhaps the emails are getting caught in your junk filter? It has always worked for me.

Comment: I keep my junk folder pretty clear, making sure something didn't go in there inadvertently.  However, I appreciate your response enough (and confirmation that the feature works) to award you the accepted answer and vote up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got an example question where you've filled in the e-mail address and not got anything? If so e-mail team@stackoverflow.com with the details I'm sure they'll look into it for you.

Comment: I'm more interested in someone actually answering my question.  I have tried emailing the "team" and got less than stellar support last time.  I figured this would be more effective.

Comment: So far, email has never worked for me, even though I watch my domain's mail logs closely. There is 'stackoverflow' in my mail address, so it is pretty easy to track down. Never found such mails (or mail attempts) in my mail log.